# A simple inequality that arises from the exact form for the prime-counting function and the second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, inequalities

The germ of this post arises when I was trying to think what terms of the so-called exact form of the prime-counting function satisfy an inequality of the form $\text{term}(x+y)\leq \text{term}(x)+\text{term}(y)$, or of the form  $\text{term}(x+y)\leq \text{term}(x)+\text{term}(y)$.

Is in the literature several problems related to the prime-counting function $\pi(x)$, one of the most famous is the Riemann hypothesis. Riemann provide us a formula, called the exact form, that you can see in the section *Exact form* of the Wikipedia [*Prime counting function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Exact_form). But is in the literature other unsolved problem, 
a less famous problem the *Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture*, see the corresponding [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture)

My belief is the following conjecture should be easy to get, since I believe that the mistery of these unsolved problems does not lie in the term that I evoke in the following conjecture, any case I believe that this question is interesting for this site, and I'm curious to know how you analyze the inequality.

**Conjecture.** *For real numbers* $x\geq 2$ *and* $y\geq 2$ *the following inequality holds*

$$\begin{multline}
 \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{\log x}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{\log y}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{\log (x+y)}\right)\right) \\
\leq\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{\log y}-\frac{1}{\log (x+y)}.
\end{multline}$$

> **Question.** Can you prove previous conjecture? **Many thanks.**

I know methods to solve inequalities more easy than this.

Comment: I don't know if the best tag is (analytic-number-theory), or there is a tag more suitable than this, if this question is welcome an interesting, feel free to add/remove those tags more suitable. Feel free to comment if it is possible to improve the mathematical content of my post.

Comment: Note that there's an easy proof for when x=y. If one sets f(x) to be the RHS - LHS in your above proposed inequality, then it is not too hard to see that the limit as x goes to infinity is 0, and to check that f'(x) is negative except for a pole a little smaller than 2.  If f(x) was negative for some x in that range, then one would have a contradiction.

Comment: Many thanks to you @JoshuaZ and Stopple for yours contributions, usually in my home I am going to take notes as remarks in a notebook.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: We have the series expansion
$$
\arctan(\pi/z)/\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k+1)z^{2k+1}}
$$
with $z$ respectively $\log(x)$, $\log(y)$, and $\log(x+y)$.  This is an alternating series with terms tending to $0$.  Since the partial sums alternately overestimates and underestimates the sum, it would suffice to prove the simpler inequality
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(x+y)^3}\le\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(x)^3}+\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(y)^3}-\frac{\pi^4}{5\log(x)^5}-\frac{\pi^4}{5\log(y)^5}.
$$

---

Update:  For $y\ge 12$,
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(y)^3}-\frac{\pi^4}{5\log(y)^5}>0,
$$
and for any fixed $x$, as $y\to\infty$
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(x+y)^3}\to 0,
$$
so certainly as $y\to\infty$
$$
\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(x+y)^3}\le\frac{\pi^2}{3\log(x)^3}-\frac{\pi^4}{5\log(x)^5}.
$$
Thus the desired inequality holds in the region  above some curve, $y\ge y(x)$ (and the same reversing the roles of $x$ and $y$.)

Comment: Many thanks, I am going to study it, seems very elegant.

Comment: @user142929 See update.